# Lenovo computer, monitor ACER ET221Q, no display, OS: Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hdmi

I have an Acer monitor which was working perfectly. For few days I did not operate the monitor. After that it is not working. Background light is coming when I plug to power. No “no signal message” on screen with or without connecting to computer. My computer is working when I connect to another monitor using the same HDMI cable. I checked by connecting using VGA cable, same result.

The model number is ET221Q. Let me know the probable problem.